# bash_rematch and regex (with nested parens)

Tags: regex, bash, match

I'm having trouble with a regex, I need search and remove the pattern matching the regex, when found I need to trim out. I wrote a regex like that

```
regex='(.*)((aa[[:space:]]bb)|(awd)|(bab)|(bc[[:space:]]d))(*.)'
```

in which I define all the beginning (1), the portion in which can be the target (2) and all the ending (3).
It's easy with simple regex like (.*)(abc)(.*)
string="abc"; regex='(*.)(abc)(.*)'

```
[[ $string =~ $regex) && myvar=${BASH_REMATCH[2]} && buffer=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
```

The trouble begin when I define a regex with nested parens and OR groups, like the first regex posted here.
This is a sample from my shell:

```
$ string=" foo bar baz bac"
$ regex='(.*)((hello[[:space:]]world)|(example)|(funk[[:space:]]you)|(bar[[:space:]]baz))(.*)'

$ [[ $string =~ $regex ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
foo
$ [[ $string =~ $regex ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
bar baz
$ [[ $string =~ $regex ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[3]}

$ [[ $string =~ $regex ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[4]}

$ [[ $string =~ $regex ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[5]}

$ [[ $string =~ $regex ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[6]}
bar baz
$ [[ $string =~ $regex ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[7]}
bac
$ [[ $string =~ $regex ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[@]}
foo bar baz bac foo bar baz bar baz bac
```

The matching have a strange behaviour, I don't find the other portion of the input string in ${BASH_REMATCH[3]} although is in the 3rd parens of the regex.
What's happen with nested parens?

Answer (score 4):

`bash` assigns numbers to the capture groups based on a left-to-right ordering of the opening parentheses. Basically, it's a depth-first ordering, not breadth-first like you are assuming.

```
1. (.*)
2. (
3.   (hello[[:space:]]world)|
4.   (example)|
5.   (funk[[:space:]]you)|
6.   (bar[[:space:]]baz)
   )
7. (.*)
```

In this regular expression, group 2 is essentially a copy of whichever of groups 3, 4, 5 or 6 actually matches, since group 2 contains nothing else. Group 7 is what you think of as the 3rd parenthesis group.

Group 0 is the entire match, which explains your last line using `@`:

```
$ [[ $string =~ $regex ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[@]}
foo bar baz bac foo bar baz bar baz bac
|             | | | |     | |     | | |
+-------------+ +-+ +-----+ +-----+ +-+
       0         1     2       6     7
```

(The empty groups 3, 4, and 5 are swallowed up as whitespace during word-splitting.)

Comment: I don't understand why the pattern "bar baz" match 2 times, in same example the target is in group 2 and 5, in this example the target is in group 2 and 6. What changes from one instance to another? I'm using always the same regex (.*)((foo)|(bar)|(baz))(.*)

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. That's a different regular expression; what string (or strings) are you matching against it?

Comment: `bar baz` matches twice because it is contained in group 6 explicitly, and in group 2 because group 2 contains group 6.

Comment: Your confusion may be in part because `bash` doesn't have non-capture groups. Any parenthesized regular expression is automatically captured, whether you want it to or not.

Comment: another regex like another configuration of pattern, hello world | aaabb | sample | bar baz

Comment: I guess to satisfy my needs I need to bring back my regex to a basic and easy form (.*)(foo)(.*) and steer the flow with bash if regex_statement elif another_regex_statement elif .. elif, and go on. I don't know how make a regex to match this kind of expression always and only in the second parens

Comment: Thanks you so much, I finally got the hang of the brackets, clear. There is a way to tell bash to not match inside the nested parens? It would be wonderful match only the first level parens